# Internet instability with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, system-installation, internet, download-speed

For a few days now, my internet speed after setting dual-boot with Win10 and Ubuntu has been very unstable. My speed will do from 90mbps to 1mbps regularly.

I've done some reading and tried a few things,but still no dice. First, I disabled IPv6, and I got faster speeds overall, but no help with stability. Then I changed my powersave config from 3 to 2... still nothing.I ran a check on my ethernet drivers; you can see the results here:

```bsh
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 0c
       serial: b4:2e:99:c3:9a:05
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-44-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7500000-f7500fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

My capacity and speed are all good, but I don't know where to start on tackling this problem.

Edit: I've come to the conclusion that this is an issue with my hardware and drivers. I built this computer to be a Windows machine, and didn't plan for compatibility with Linux.

Comment: That Ethernet adapter is decently supported. If you’re getting only 1mbps from a gigabit Ethernet connection in Linux and full speed in Windows, it’s most likely a misconfigured flag somewhere 

Comment: Can you explain that to me? I don't really know what a misconfigured flag is.